# Access ADLS Gen2 objects based on tier (Hot, Cool)

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

I need to move objects from Hot tier to Cool tier, which I was able to achieve using "Life Cycle Management" by creating some rules.

Now I need to read all the object names which now has been moved to Cool tier using a Synapse notebook or by any other means.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the procedure below to list the objects in an ADLS account:

Go to `Shared access signature` and generate a connection string with the following permissions:

[image]

Copy the connection string as shown below:

[image]

Use the following code to list the objects in a Synapse notebook:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

connection_string = "<connectionString>"
container_name = "<container>"

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()
for blob in blob_list:
  if blob.blob_tier == "Cool":
    print(blob.name)
```

This will list the objects as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response @Bhavani. Is the same possible using a Service Principal?

Comment: Yes, you can use Service Principal